# On Converting Time getting a - value ,Is possible to correct the code?

Tags: ios, swift, time

On coverting time getting a - ve Value  means if converting 13.30 to 01.30 PM Getting as -1.30PM and if 09.30 AM getting correct for this code:

```
 houRString = 13  &   minTString =30

 if let min = Int(houRString!),let sec = Int(minTString!) {
   var totalSec = (min * 60) + sec
   totalSec += 0
   let min = (totalSec/60) > 12 ? 12 - (totalSec/60) : (totalSec/60)
   cell.patTimeTxt.text = String(format: "%02d.%02d %@", min,(totalSec%60),((Int(houRString!) ?? 0) > 12 ? "PM" : "AM"))
 }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just replace

```
cell.patTimeTxt.text = String(format: "%02d.%02d %@", min,(totalSec%60),((Int(houRString!) ?? 0) > 12 ? "PM" : "AM"))
```

with

```
cell.patTimeTxt.text = String(format: "%02d.%02d %@", abs(min) , (totalSec % 60), (min > 12 ? "PM" : "AM"))
```

Here the change is `abs(min)` which will convert negative values to positive. And this will resolve your issue but accourding to me correct way to do it is with `DateFormatter` check below example:

```
let houRString = "13"

let minTString = "30"

let str = "\(houRString):\(minTString)"
let dateFormatter = DateFormatter()
dateFormatter.locale = Locale(identifier: "en_US_POSIX")
dateFormatter.dateFormat = "H:mm"
if let inDate = dateFormatter.date(from: str) {
    dateFormatter.dateFormat = "hh:mm a"
    let time = dateFormatter.string(from:inDate)
    print("time in 12 hour is: \(time)") //"time in 12 hour is: 01:30 PM\n"
}
```

Comment: The use of the date formatter here may cause problems. You are creating a date in some unknown default year with unknown possible side effects due to changes in early dates and possible DST issues.

Comment: convert 12 to 24 this code getting error?    let str = timeLbl.text!
        let dateFormatter = DateFormatter()
        dateFormatter.dateFormat = "hh:mm "
        if let inDate = dateFormatter.date(from: str) {
            dateFormatter.dateFormat = "H:mm" 
            let time = dateFormatter.string(from:inDate)
            print("time in 24 hour is: \(time)") //"time in 24 hour is: 13:30 PM\n"
        }

Comment: getting 01.30 itself not change to 13.30

Comment: dateFormatter.dateFormat = "H:mm"

Comment: but then you need to replace `hh:mm a` with `H:mm`

Comment: yes get, hour is: 16:30 but on splitting get error: let hourString = time.split(separator: ":").first   as:Value of type '(UnsafeMutablePointer<time_t>?) -> time_t' (aka '(Optional<UnsafeMutablePointer<Int>>) -> Int') has no member 'split'

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/191719/discussion-between-sruthi-c-sankar-and-dharmesh).

Answer (score 2):

Your problem is that you are subtracting 13 hours from 12 `12 - (totalSec/60)` instead of subtracting 12 from 13 `(totalSec/60) - 12`.

So you just need to just change

```
let min = (totalSec/60) > 12 ? 12 - (totalSec/60) : (totalSec/60)
```

to

```
let min = (totalSec/60) > 12 ? (totalSec/60) - 12 : (totalSec/60)
```

I would also change the string format to `"%02d:%02d %@"` and your var naming is misleading (you are using totalSec where it is actually the total numbers of minutes) and there is no need to calculate the total number of minutes:

```
let houRString = "13"
let minTString = "30"

if let hour = Int(houRString), let min = Int(minTString) {
    let hourAMPM = hour > 12 ? hour - 12 : hour
    let amPM = hour > 12 ? "PM" : "AM"
    print(String(format: "%02d:%02d %@", hourAMPM, min, amPM))  // "01:30 PM\n"
}
```

Comment: Does `totalSec/60` returns minutes or hours?

Comment: totalSec/60 is the number of hours = 13

Comment: @Kamran OP naming is definitely misleading

Comment: May be i need coffee. But i believe `minutes = seconds/60 and hours = seconds/3600`. I think OP is making completely wrong calculation. OR may be i am not getting anything :)

Comment: @Kamran check my last edit. This is a classic example where bad naming can get you totally confused.